# generate a random normal variable which is uncorrelated with errors in R

Tags: r, regression, correlation, econometrics

I generated an error in r

u1<-rnorm(n, mean=0, sd=1);

And I want to generate a random normal variable x ~ i.i.d.N(n, 0, 4) but this is not correlated with u1 i.e. corr(x, u1)=0

How can define this in R

Comment: it is sufficient that you run  x= rnorm(n, 0, 4), this will be uncorrelated with your u1

Comment: but when I calculate its correlation, I obtain core(x, u1)= 0.4. How to reduce this value? @HardCore

Comment: I run it and I obtain 0.003 with n=10000. you can test statistically that this is different than zero. Even a simple regression will do.

Comment: well, this is a good point! How can I run this test in R to check the correlation value is statistically equal to zero or not? Can you write its code? please. Thank you. @HardCore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested in the comment in order to test the correlation you can simply use

```
cor.test(u1,x)
```

this is a code that creates a matrix with stored estimates of correlation and t statistic as the sample size varies

```
c1 = matrix(, 5,2)
i=1
for (n in c(100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000)){
      u1<-rnorm(n, 0, 1)
      x= rnorm(n, 0, 4)
      c1[i,1]=cor(u1,x)
      c1[i,2]=cor.test(u1,x)$statistic
      i= i+1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let'S draw the two random variables in a function like

```
set.seed(1)

two.random <- function(n){
  list(x = rnorm(n, 0, 1),
       y = rnorm(n, 0, 4))
}
```

Now we call this 10 times with $n=10$ an print the correlations:

```
replicate(10, {example <- two.random(n = 10);
round(cor(example[["x"]], example[["y"]]),3)})
```

The result is

```
 [1] -0.294 -0.552 -0.275  0.089 -0.235  0.203  0.481
 [8]  0.230 -0.448 -0.285
```

Now we do the same thing with $n=1000$

```
replicate(10, {example <- two.random(n = 1000);
round(cor(example[["x"]], example[["y"]]),3)}
```

resulting in

```
 [1]  0.022 -0.015 -0.041  0.010  0.037  0.047 -0.012
 [8] -0.030  0.016 -0.002
```

an  with $n=100,000$ the result is

```
 [1]  0.001  0.002 -0.005  0.001  0.008  0.009  0.002
 [8]  0.005 -0.003 -0.001
```

As you can see, the correlation coefficient is not zero but it gets nearer and nearer to zero the more random samples you draw.

In practice, you will want to use the function `cor.test` which gives you a $p$-value as well as a 95% confidence interval for the *'true'* correlation.

```
set.seed(1)
n <- 100
test <- cor.test(rnorm(n, 0, 1), rnorm(n, 0, 4))
print(test$conf.int)
print(test$p.value)
```

Larger sample sizes $n$ will give you closer confidence intervalls. But in 95% of the cases, the 0 will be in the confidence intervall.